# Using "x:" in an XML element name

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create an XML file that needs to be sent to a server, with this format:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:sen2="http://www.some_url.com">
<x:Header>
```

I'm working with Python 3 and the lxml library, but when trying to create the element I get an error.

Test code:

```
def authSendDataExtraccion():
    envelope = etree.Element("x:Envelope")
    debug_XML(envelope)
```

Result:

```
ValueError: Invalid tag name 'x:Envelope'
```

How can I use the ":" character in the element and attribute names?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. I have edited conversational language out of your question, and made sure the question is asked clearly - because here we care about *the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `nsmap` to create an element in a namespace:

```
envelope = etree.Element("Envelope", nsmap={'x': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'})
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, I solve it using the "E-Factory" tool in the lxml library, 
[link](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-e-factory)